# Adicionar valores de um inner join a 2 variaveis

Tags: php, mysql

Gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma de pegar os resultados de um select separado através do php.
Eu tenho duas chaves estrangeiras na mesma tabela, setando para o mesmo lugar, são elas tj.fk_time_mandante e tj.fk_time_visitante.

```
SELECT tt.ds_nome, tti.ds_nome
FROM tb_jogo AS tj INNER JOIN tb_time AS tt ON tj.fk_time_mandante = tt.id_time
INNER JOIN tb_time AS tti ON tj.fk_time_visitante = tti.id_time
```

já utilizei o mysql_fetch_array mas ele junta os tt.ds_nome e tti.ds_nome, queria que eles fosse inseridos em variáveis separadas
Exemplo:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
 echo $row['ds_nome1']; <- para tt.ds_time da consulta
 echo $row['ds_nome2']; <- para tti.ds_time da consulta
}
```

Já testei a consulta no banco de dados, e retornou o resultado correto.
Obs.: não estou usando nenhum framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dê um alias (apelido) para suas colunas usando **AS**. Isso não é do PHP, mas sim, SQL padrão. Veja mais: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp

```
SELECT tt.ds_nome AS ds_nome1, tti.ds_nome AS ds_nome2
FROM tb_jogo AS tj INNER JOIN tb_time AS tt ON tj.fk_time_mandante = tt.id_time
INNER JOIN tb_time AS tti ON tj.fk_time_visitante = tti.id_time
```